# php7 session variables getting changed while refresh the page in concurrent access - cloud hosting

Tags: php

Assume two users (A and B) are logged in a PHP application.

While both the session going on A session variable are shown to B and vice versa while accessing the same page in the application.

If A refreshes the page his original session values are shown again.

How to avoid this problem ? Please help me.

login page:

```
session_start();
```

error_reporting(0);
ob_start();

if( (isset($_POST['submit'])) && ($_POST['submit'] == 'login') ) {

```
$username=addslashes(trim($_POST['stud_id']));
$password=addslashes(trim($_POST['password']));
```

}

$mysqli->set_charset('utf8');
$query=sprintf("select * from registation_fst where Application_id='%s'",$username);

```
 $result = $mysqli->query($query) or die($mysqli->error);
 $rowcount = mysqli_num_rows($result);

  if($rowcount > 0)
    { 
        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);


        $adm_pass= addslashes($row['Password']);
        $adm_user= addslashes($row['Application_id']);


        if(($username == $adm_user) && ($password == $adm_pass) )
        {


                $_SESSION['username']=$row['Application_id'];
                //$_SESSION['password']=$row['Password'];


                $_SESSION['mob'] = $row['Mobile_No'];
                $_SESSION['dob'] = $row['DOB'];
                $_SESSION['aadhar_no'] = $row['Adhar_no'];
                $_SESSION['zone'] = $row['Zonal_id'];
                $_SESSION['fullname'] = $row['FullName'];

                $_SESSION['loggedin_time'] = time();

                $db_sessionid=$row['Session_id'];
                $old_sessionid = session_id();
                $new_sessionid = session_regenerate_id(true);
                $_SESSION['newregid']=$new_sessionid;
                $_SESSION['odlregid']=$old_sessionid;



                if(!empty($old_sessionid))
                {

                $query_time=$mysqli->query("UPDATE registation_fst SET Session_id='".$old_sessionid."'WHERE Application_id='".$_SESSION['username']."'");

                        header("Location:Login-home.php");exit;

                } else if($db_sessionid!=$_SESSION['odlregid'])
                {

                    $query_time=$mysqli->query("UPDATE registation_fst SET Session_id ='".$new_sessionid."'WHERE Application_id='".$_SESSION['username']."'");

                    header("Location:Login-home.php");exit;
                }

        } else{
            $_SESSION['logstu']= "wrong";
            header("Location:Login.php");
                exit;
        }
    } else{
            $_SESSION['logstu']= "notavail";
            header("Location:Login.php");
                exit;

}
```

home page:

```
<?php
session_start();
 ob_start();
 print_R($_SESSION);
 ?>
```

session values getting changing automatically and reverting back again on refresh

Comment: We can't help you without a minimum working example code. Post the code with an explanation where exactly is the error.

Comment: Maybe you have a mistage in some server-side caching?
Only god can tell without code or some debugging effort ;-)

Maybe the guide https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask can help you to improve you're question a bit.

Happy to help and welcome to stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

welcome to community.try some changing to your ob_start().

maybe write it before session_start or remove it just to know if it is problem.